# rails 4 how to use where and where in condition simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following query

```
model = (1,2,3,4)
@posts = Post.where(category_id: id,  product_model_id: model)
```

My above query is justing taking the `1` from model how can i use `where in` condition over here

**Edit-1**

This piece of code works but I don't feel this as a good code right?

```
@posts = Post.where("category_id = ? and product_model_id in (#{model})", id)
```

**Edit-2**

If I use

@posts = Post.where("category_id = ? and product_model_id in (?)", id, model)

Throwing error as

`invalid input syntax for integer: "15,16"` because my input is like this

`select * from posts where category_id=5 and product_model_id in ('15,16')`

How to correct it then..

Comment: The code is subject to injection, you can't have: model = (1,2,3,4) in ruby are you refering to an array???

Comment: @bjhaid Please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
model_ids = model.split(",").map(&:to_i)
@posts = Post.where(category_id: id, product_model_id: model_ids)
```

or

```
model_ids = model.split(",").map(&:to_i)
@posts = Post.where("category_id = ? AND product_model_id IN (?)", id, model_ids)
```

Comment: you can simply use `user_ids = User.all.ids` and then `Post.where("user_id in (?)", user_ids)`

Answer (score 25):

According to the rails guide, you can pass in an array to `where` and it should understand that you want to use IN. See the guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions

I'm a little confused by your syntax, since `model = (1, 2, 3, 4)` doesn't look like valid array syntax.

Relevant part of the guide:

```
Client.where(orders_count: [1,3,5])
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use arel, but I'd just do something like:

`@posts = Post.where("category_id = ? AND product_model_id IN (?)", id, model)`